# Retain the size of a cell.imageView irrespective of the image size

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uitableview, uiimageview

I have a `UITableViewCell` which contains a `UIImageView` that resizes itself depending on the size of its image. Please could you tell me how I could retain the size of the `UIImageView` irrespective of the size of the image.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generally speaking, a `UIImageView` doesn't resize in response to the size of the image. What does happen, is that the `UIImageView` will not clip the contents, so that you see the image exceeding the `UIImageView` bounding frame.

You could make the `UIImageView` resize the image to fit into the box, by doing

```
imageview.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
```

or to fill the box:

```
imageview.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
```

or you could let it crop the image:

```
imageview.clipsToBounds = YES;
```